# How to add an npm package inside stencil js project?

Tags: stenciljs, npm-package

I am creating a stencil project which uses an npm package inside it, is there any options to add an npm package inside stencil project. Any suggestions I searching for a solution for quite a while.

This is how i use ck-editor in angular

```
<ck-editor name="editor" #myEditor [(ngModel)]="templateSetValue.template_content"
            (change)="handleEditorData($event)">
        </ck-editor>
```

Is it possible to use the same is stencil project
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-ckeditor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly, but to add a package from npm in your Stencil.js project, you can just install it, like you would in any other node project:

```
npm install <some-package>
```

For example `nprogress`:

```
npm install nprogress @types/nprogress
```

and then import it in your code like

```js
import nprogress from 'nprogress';

nprogress.start();

// ...
```

Comment: I have to use ckeditor inside my stencil project 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-ckeditor

<ck-editor name="editor" #myEditor [(ngModel)]="templateSetValue.template_content"
            (change)="handleEditorData($event)">
        </ck-editor>
this is how i use in angular, how can I use it in stencil

Comment: It looks like that package is written specifically for use in Angular projects, so how do you expect it to work without Angular? It's probably just a wrapper package that allows to easily integrate CKEditor into an Angular project. Without Angular, you'll have to use the CKEditor packages directly, e. g. `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic` (see https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/installation.html#npm).

Comment: the above package nprogress will it work in stencil projects?
If so can u give me a working example. I'm completely new to stenciljs pls help

Comment: Yes `nprogress` works with stencil. https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-gagarin-rw7j5?file=/src/index.html. Note that `nprogress` comes without styling by default, which is why nothing is visible unless you write some styling. See `#nprogress` styles in `src/global.css`.

Comment: Can u suggest me a multi select dropdown package with search on top (ngx-select dropdown is which I normally use in angulat) which works in stencil project, and finally the stencil component should be integrated to angular

Comment: I tried nprogress, it working fine in stencil project and when i integrated to angular also its working. Now please suggest me a multi select dropdown package

Comment: Lol you haven't even accepted my answer yet, and you already ask me to do your job for you 

Comment: I accepted ur answer now please help with a multi select dropdown which i can use in stencil

Comment: How about this one: https://www.webcomponents.org/element/selvinfehric/multi-select-combo-box. Or you can look through https://vaadin.com/components.

Comment: How can i install and use this in stencil